# How to update has_many models at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

There is a csv file for company stock price and each company have `code` column that is unique. But main column of `Company` model is `id`.

And I want to update all prices of companies from a `CSV` file.

```
csv = CSV.parse("code,date,amount\n3000,2017-03-27,300\n4000,2017-03-27,251", headers: true, converters: [:integer, :date])
csv.each do |row|
  company_id = Company.select(:id).find_by(code: row['code'])&.id
  next if company_id.nil?
  Price.find_or_create_by(date: row['date'], amount: row['amount'], company_id: company_id)
end
```

So I had to use `each` loop like this. Is there a more efficient way to implement this function?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways of doing this, but here's one.

```
company = Company.where(code: row['code').select(:id).first
if (company)
 ...
end
```

you could also do a sql INCLUDE or LEFT JOIN on price at the expense of readability later. Or you could use .tap on the company. But I prefer being able to quickly understand what I was doing a year ago when I'm reading code.